# Keep anchor tag href from jumping to it's page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following anchor tag in my HTML that I use to load contents from that HTML location into a `contents` div on the current page. This anchor tag is part of Bootstrap treeview plugin I use for generating a table of contents:

```
<a href="/Introduction/index.html#1-1-overview1" style="color:inherit;">1.1 Overview</a>
```

In my JavaScript, I have the following code I use to listen for two events. One for the anchor tag so that I disable the default behavior and the other to process the anchor tag and load the contents and scroll to the anchor as follows:

```
    $("a[href*='#']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Add smooth scrolling to all links inside a navbar
    $treeview.on('nodeSelected', function (e, data) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (data && data.href !== "") {
            // Split location and hash
            var hash = data.href.match(/[#].*/g)[0];
            var location = data.href.match(/[^#]*/g)[0];

            if (prevLocation === location) {
                // Don't reload page if already at same location as last clicked
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 55
                }, 200);
            } else {
                prevLocation = location;
                $('#contents').load(location, function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 55
                    }, 200);
                });
            }

        }
        $body.scrollspy('refresh');
        $sideBar.affix('checkPosition');
    });
```

What I am seeing is that the first time a click a node in my TOC, it loads the HTML into the contents div as expected but the second time I click it, it loads the HTML page that is referenced in the anchor tag despite my efforts to track if I previously loaded it as I do with the conditional logic above. I also notice that on the subsequent click, the anchor selector is not being called.

Any idea how I can accomplish having the TOC initially load the HTML from another page into the current page and then on subsequent calls just scroll to the anchor location (ie., chapter)?

Comment: Did you try `return false;` as well as `preventDefault`?

Comment: can you debug it using chrome's developer tools to see what the value of prevLocation is every time?

Comment: `return false` results in the `nodeSelected` event not being called, BUT if I combine those two functions under the anchor selector, eliminating the `nodeSelected` event and return false, then it appears to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the two functions and returning false appears to work as follows:

```
     $("a[href*='#']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this && this.href !== "") {
            // Split location and hash
            var hash = this.href.match(/[#].*/g)[0];
            var location = this.href.match(/[^#]*/g)[0];

            if (prevLocation === location) {
                // Don't reload page if already at same location as last clicked
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 55
                }, 200);
            } else {
                prevLocation = location;
                $('#contents').load(location, function () {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 55
                    }, 200);
                });
            }

        }
        $body.scrollspy('refresh');
        $sideBar.affix('checkPosition');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Generally it's pretty poor form to answer a question using someone else's comment, you should give them a chance to add their own answer first.

Comment: LOL...please do answer it though. I'll delete this one and give you the credit.  Sorry I preempted you.

Comment: No need, you already did it, and you can accept your own answers here. I honestly don't care about the credit or rep, was just letting you know that some people might react badly.